# untrusted certificate error in browser ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

i have ejabberd server. and i added tls now but now in browser its showing untrusted certificate error, i have installed certificate please help me

```
> listen:
>   - 
>     port: 5280
>     module: ejabberd_http
>     request_handlers:
>       "/ws": ejabberd_http_ws
>       "/bosh": mod_bosh
>       "/api": mod_http_api
>       "/presence": mod_webpresence
>     web_admin: true
>     tls: true
>     certfile: "/etc/ejabberd/server.pem"
```

Comment: can you add the error, and the code where you initialize the connection?

Comment: @OrYaacov actually its now working fine in ie on other browser its showing as "your connection to this site is not secure"